# Configure Vs code version 2.0.0 Build Task for python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I need help in configuring my Vs code to run scripts in python using Cntrl Shift B, I was working fine until Vs code upgraded to  version 2.0.0 now it wants me to configure the Build. And I am clueless what Build is all about.

In the past it worked well when I only needed to configure the task runner. There are youtube videos for the task runner. I cant seem to lay my finger on what the Build is all about.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In VS Code go Tasks -> Configure Tasks

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "Run File",
            "command": "python ${file}",
            "type": "shell",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "new",
                "focus": true
            }
        },
        {
            "taskName": "nosetest",
            "command": "nosetests -v",
            "type": "shell",
            "group": {
                "kind": "test",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "new",
                "focus": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

`command`: runs current python file

`group`: 'build'

`presentation`:

- always shows the shell when run
- uses a new shell
- focuses the shell (i.e. keyboard is captured in shell window)

2nd Task is configured as the default test and just runs `nosetest -v` in the folder that's currently open in VS Code.

The "Run Build Task" (the one that's bound to `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`B`) is the one that's configured as the default build task, task 1 in this example (see the `group` entry).

EDIT:
Suggested by @RafaelZayas in the comments (this will use the Python interpreter that's specified in VS Code's settings rather than the system default; see his comment for more info):

`"command": "${command:python.interpreterPath} ${file}"`

Comment: I tried you code but it shows me error `> Executing task: python d:\books\programming Languages\python\Projects\.vscode\tasks.json <

C:\Users\[myuser]\Anaconda3\python.exe: can't open file 'd:\books\programming': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1`

Comment: May I recommend:     "command": "${config:python.pythonPath} ${file}"`    replacing python with the config variable will use the same pythonPath as is set in the python VS Code Extension.    If on windows, this will run with cmd.exe, or PowerShell.  Depending on which (I think PowerShell is for Win 10 or later), put a single or double quote around the $file variable, i.e. "command":"${config:python.pythonPath} '${file}'"

Comment: awesome configuration, works as charm. Just wanted to add that they have recently changed `taskName` to `label`, not a biggie, just warnings in VS Code.

Comment: I have added a minor edit as the newest way to use the Python interpreter from venv or folder settings was outdated. See more here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/11789#issuecomment-631413067.

The new way is: "command": "${command:python.interpreterPath} ${file}"

Comment: `${command:python.interpreterPath}` this bit :thumbsup:

Answer (score 6):

...Don't have enough reputation to comment on the accepted answer...

At least in my environment (Ubuntu 18.04, w/ virtual env) if arguments are being passed in with "args", the file *must* be the first argument, as @VladBezden is doing, and not part of the command as @orangeInk is doing. Otherwise I get the message "No such file or directory".

Specifically, the answer @VladBezden has *does* work for me, where the following does *not*.

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "${config:python.pythonPath} setup.py", // WRONG, move setup.py to args
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "args": [
                "install"
            ],
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "panel": "shared",
                "focus": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This took me a while to figure out, so I thought I would share.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my configuration for the build (Ctrl+Shift+B)

#### tasks.json

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "python",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "args": [
                "setup.py",
                "install"
            ],
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "panel": "shared",
                "focus": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```