# Configure task using python in visual studio code for windows 10

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I'm using vs code 2.0 with python 3.6 and want to configure a task to run he the current python file. The `tasks.json` file has the below lines

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "echo",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "echo Hello"
    }
]
}
```

How to fill the lines to fit my needs. I tried many solutions with no avail, especially the one here [Configure Vs code version 2.0.0 Build Task for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45409845/configure-vs-code-version-2-0-0-build-task-for-python) it shows the below error

```
> Executing task: python d:\books\programming Languages\python\Projects\.vscode\tasks.json <  
C:\Users\[myuser]\Anaconda3\python.exe: can't open file 'd:\books\programming': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
 The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

Please help in steps because I'm very new to python.

Comment: I'm not familiar with VS Code, but the problem is with the space in `programming Languages'  in the path, you either need to escape the space with a backslash or surround the path with quotes or change the directory name to remove the space.

Comment: It works, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Minimum configuration:

```
{
            "version": "2.0.0",
            "command": "python",
            "args":["${file}"]
        }
```

Optimal configuration you can find here:

[Configure Vs code version 2.0.0 Build Task for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45409845/configure-vs-code-version-2-0-0-build-task-for-python)