# Run Button in Vs Code only allows running using debugger

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I run my code in Visual Studio Code using the run button, it is stuck on the Python Debugger: debug using launch.json.
However, I just want it to run my code through the coderunner.
[this picture shows my problem. Notice the run has a bug on it and I just want it to run regularly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k4fM.jpg)

I do not know what causes this problem and I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: There is a little arrow next to the button, that expands a drop down. It is possible the option you are looking for can be selected there.

Comment: Also if possible, could you add the contents of your `launch.json` file to your question?
It should be in the directory `.vscode`.

Comment: You can add a "!" before the image link to make it visible.

Comment: @Nice Zombies, Users with less than 10 reputation cannot post images. See [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268469/12559207) for why.

Answer (score 2):

Click the drop-down arrow next to the button, and choose "Run Python File":

[image: drop-down list]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, is there a way to simply click the run button and have it run the code without having to click on the drop-down?

Comment: It remembers your last choice or you can add a keybinding.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a "[default build task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks)" in VS Code to run Python code (without debugging) by pressing `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`B` on the keyboard.

To add the task, go to (in the main menue of VS Code)
-> `Terminal`
-> `Configure Default Build Task`
-> `Create tasks.json file from template`
-> `Others`,
and replace the existing code in tasks.json by the code below.

With a Python file opended in a tab in VS Code, you can run the respective file by pressing `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`B` on the keyboard. Feedback like print statements etc will appear in the terminal.

The code below is a [slightly modified version of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45409930/9524424).

```
{
    // https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "command": "${command:python.interpreterPath} ${file}",
            "type": "shell",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "new",
                "focus": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "label": "Run File"
        }
    ]
}
```